# Delaying Jquery CSS Animation using mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I've been trying to put 10 seconds delay on this jquery css animation which is dependent on mousemove. I've tried unsuccesfully utilizing both .delay and  .setInterval right before like so:

```
$(document).delay(10000).ready(function ()
```

However, they don't seem to be working for me. Its possible that I put it in the wrong place. I have listed below a the jsfiddle link with the code. If someone can help me out would be amazing.

JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/oekhedr/eeh950b7/39/#&togetherjs=4Bsp9CVtlB

Thank you so much

Comment: You want the element to have the rotate3d transform applied 10 seconds after the mousemove event, or to only happen 10 seconds after the document is ready, or something else?

Comment: Max thanks for writing. Exactly so the rotate3d transform will apply after 10 seconds. So for the first 10s that element stays put exactly where it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a (plain JavaScript) setTimeout in your mousemove event, like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // do something here, but it will only start after 10 seconds have passed
},10000);
```

`.delay()` only works with certain jQuery effects.  Here is a fiddle using your code: https://jsfiddle.net/eeh950b7/42/

Comment: Thank you so much Max for the help :)